# Why this snippet is not pure?

Tags: javascript, purely-functional

When I watch Google Chrome Developers,
https://youtu.be/qaGjS7-qWzg?t=636

They said this snippet is not pure. I don't know why.

```
const g = new Map();

for (const [u,v] of edges) {
    if (!g.has(u))
        g.set(u, []);
    if (!g.has(v))
        g.set(v, []);
    g.get(u).push(v)
}
```

And they also mentioned this is pure,

```
const startPoints = new Set(edges.map(([u, v]) => u));

const g = new Map(
  [...startPoints].map(startPoint =>
    edges.filter(([u, v]) => u == startPoint).map(([u, v]) => v)
  )
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we talk about purity in a system we are talking about a system that doesn't change the observable state.

- In the first script at line 1 `g` is an empty `Map` and by the last line it is not. Its value was mutated.
- In the second script `startPoints` is the same thing at line one and at the end.

To make it a little easy, let me explain it with a function. Let's suppose you have a function that giving an array of numbers it multiply it by 2. So if:

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
multiply(a)
// a = [2, 4, 6]
```

This function is not pure. It has changed the observable state of the system that in this case is `a`. But if:

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = multiply(a)
// a = [1, 2, 3]
// b = [2, 4, 6]
```

This function is pure. `a` didn't change.

Comment: So you can't use something like `pop`, `push` in the pure world? Seems You have to assign a new variable when you want to mutate an Object/Array every time.

Comment: Exactly in a pure world (that JavaScript is not), you create new copies every time you want to mutate the state. In JS there is a lib that does that https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/.